# How to pass props to component passed to MenuItem in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code to render a notification menu

```
      <Menu
        anchorEl={notificationAnchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
        open={isNotificationMenuOpen}
        onClose={this.handleNotificationMenuClose}
      >
        {notifications.map(notification => (
          <MenuItem
            key={notification.id}
            component={NotificationItem}
            onClick={this.handleNotificationMenuClose}
          />
        ))}
      </Menu>
```

What I don't understand is how do I pass props to the `NotificationItem` Component using the `notification` object I have.

Comment: Can you explain what `MenuItem` does, or what you want it to do?

Comment: Which version of Material UI are you using?

Comment: MenuItem is a material-ui component https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/

Comment: @darksmurf 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just render a `NotificationItem` inside the `MenuItem` if that is what you want.

Also, remember to pass a unique `key` prop to each element mapped from an array.

```
<Menu
    anchorEl={notificationAnchorEl}
    anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
    transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
    open={isNotificationMenuOpen}
    onClose={this.handleNotificationMenuClose}
>
    {notifications.map((notification, i) => (
        <MenuItem
           key={i}
           onClick={this.handleNotificationMenuClose}
        >
            <NotificationItem someProp={notification.someProp}/>
        </MenuItem>
    ))}
</Menu>
```

Comment: That's..wrong. If you look at the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/#props), the type for component props is `Component`, it is also elaborated "The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a DOM element or a **component**."

Comment: That's right, you can use a component if you want to, but then you can't pass any props to it (as was requested by your question). Therefore you should place the component inside the MenuItem itself instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `key` prop however, I would probably have  faced issues later

Comment: I found the way to do so in the [implementation of the `ListItem`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js) of all places...is it OK to post answers to your own question?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear. If you think you have a better answer, sure you can answer your own question.

Comment: Although I would appreciate it if you removed the first first two lines from the answer since they are incorrect and I wouldn't want to spread misinformation

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the answer in the [implementation of the ListItem Component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js).

Turns out that all the additional props given to `ListItem` are passed on the to `component`.

```js
const {
  component: componentProp,
  ...other
} = props;

const componentProps = { className, disabled, ...other };
let Component = componentProp || 'li';

return (
  <ContainerComponent
    className={classNames(classes.container, ContainerClassName)}
    {...ContainerProps}
  >
    <Component {...componentProps}>{children}</Component>
    {children.pop()}
  </ContainerComponent>
);
```

^ relevant code from `ListItem.js`

So the following code will work

```js
 {notifications.map(notification => (
   <MenuItem
     component={NotificationItem}
     onClick={this.handleNotificationMenuClose}
     notification={notification}
   />
  ))}
```

Comment: Although this works, It would be great if someone could explain how this would work with typescript since it would cause typing issues if I try to add `NotificationItem` props to `MenuItem`.